# Unexpected result with left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two tables. One is the `coche` table and another `ruta`:

Table `coche`:

```
pk_coche    modelo      
-------------------
1           Model 1
2           Model 2 
3           Model 3
```

Table `ruta`:

```
pk_ruta     fk_coche    kms_inicio     kms_final
-------------------------------------------------
1           1           200.000        210.000
2           3           100.000        110.000  
3           3           110.000        120.000    
4           1           210.000        0
```

The column of `kms_inicio` refers to the kilometers with which a car starts the route for example with `200,000 km`. As long as the column of `kms_final` is equal to 0, it means that the car is in route.

I have this query:

```
SELECT pk_coche, modelo FROM coche c
LEFT JOIN ruta r ON c.pk_coche=r.fk_coche
WHERE r.pk_ruta is null or r.kms_final > 0
```

My problem is that the query results in this:

```
pk_coche    modelo      
-------------------
1           Model 1
2           Model 2 
3           Model 3
3           Model 3
```

And the result should look like this:

```
pk_coche    modelo      
-------------------
2           Model 2 
3           Model 3
```

Since as I explained earlier when `kms_final` is equal to `0`, it means that that car is en route. I mean, the result that should appear to me would be the `Modelo 2` and `Modelo 3` cars since those have finished their routes because `kms_final` is greater than `0`.

You can see a better example on this link:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2e7ea/32

Comment: I think you have a mistake somewhere because when you join pk_coche to fk_coche there is no model2 record anywhere

Comment: Then don't use `LEFT JOIN` if you don't want every record from `coche` table

Comment: Do as buddies above mentioned have  + to remove duplicated rows use also `DISTINCT`

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: "the Modelo 2 and Modelo 3 cars since those have finished their routes because kms_final is greater than 0"....but the ruta table contains no rows relating to Modelo 2, so how do you know it's finished its route? It seems like it's never even started. If anything, the cars which have finished are 1 and 3 (and 3 has finished two routes), but car 1 has seemingly also started a new route, so perhaps it should not be included. Is it just a typo relating to Modelo 2? It's not clear.

Comment: @Xerox have you tried any of the below solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're after all cars which don't have miles recorded against them.

Try this (MS SQL):

```
SELECT pk_coche
, modelo 
FROM coche c
where not exists 
(
  select top 1 1
  from ruta r 
  where r.fk_coche = c.pk_coche
  and r.kms_final = 0
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4bff0/3)

---

#### Update: Solution for MySQL

Per updated tags, please find a solution for MySQL below.

```
SELECT pk_coche
, modelo 
FROM coche c
where not exists 
(
   select 1
   from ruta r 
   where r.fk_coche = c.pk_coche
   and r.kms_final = 0
   LIMIT 1
 )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bff0b/2)

Comment: He wants cars whose final state is 
+ Not used (so the null clause) 
+ Not on route (so the final km is greater than zero)

Comment: @Alfabravo agreed; I think that's the same as I've stated / provided a solution for, only with different wording; i.e. if no miles (kms) are recorded against the cars they're either not used, or have a zero in the usage.  Do you agree, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
select distinct a.pk_coche, modelo  from #coche a  
left join #ruda b on a.pk_coche=b.fk_coche
where b.pk_ruta is null or modelo not in(select modelo from #coche a join #ruda b on a.pk_coche=b.fk_coche where kms_final =0)
```